# How to implement this program for importing into a table without using the INSERT INTO SELECT Statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Currently the import/insert process is working perfectly. But I don't want to write a single query for both inserting and selecting but rather write a separate query for selecting from 'snomed_descriptiondata' table and separate query for inserting to 'snomedinfo'_data table.

My current code:

```
package Snomed.Snomed;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Date;

import catalog.Root;

public class Snomedinfo {
  public void snomedinfoinsert()
    {
    Root oRoot = null;
    ResultSet oRsSelect = null;
    PreparedStatement oPrStmt = null;
    PreparedStatement oPrStmt2 = null;
    PreparedStatement oPrStmtSelect = null;
    String strSql = null;
    String strSql2 = null;
    String snomedcode=null;
    ResultSet oRs = null;
    String refid = null;
    String id = null;
    String effectivetime = null;
    String active = null;
    String moduleid = null;
    String conceptid = null;
    String languagecode = null;
    String typeid = null;
    String term = null;
    String caseSignificanceid = null;
    int count = 0;
    final int batchSize = 1000;
    try{
    oRoot = Root.createDbConnection(null);
    strSql = "SELECT  id FROM snomed_conceptdata WHERE active=1 ";
    oPrStmt2 = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(strSql);
    oRsSelect = oPrStmt2.executeQuery();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO snomedinfo_data (refid,id,effectivetime,active,moduleid,conceptid,languagecode,typeid,term,caseSignificanceid)SELECT refid,id,effectivetime,active,moduleid,conceptid,languagecode,typeid,term,caseSignificanceid from snomed_descriptiondata WHERE conceptid =? AND active=1" ; 
    oPrStmtSelect = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    while (oRsSelect.next()) {
        snomedcode = Root.TrimString(oRsSelect.getString("id"));
        //String sql = "INSERT INTO snomedinfo_data (refid,id,effectivetime,active,moduleid,conceptid,languagecode,typeid,term,caseSignificanceid)SELECT refid,id,effectivetime,active,moduleid,conceptid,languagecode,typeid,term,caseSignificanceid from snomed_descriptiondata WHERE conceptid =? AND active=1" ; 
        //oPrStmtSelect = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        oPrStmtSelect.setString(1,snomedcode);

        oPrStmtSelect.executeUpdate();                 
        }

    //oPrStmtSelect.executeBatch();
    System.out.println("done");
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        oRsSelect = Root.EcwCloseResultSet(oRsSelect);
        oRs = Root.EcwCloseResultSet(oRs);
        oPrStmt = Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(oPrStmt);
        oPrStmt = Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(oPrStmt2);
        oPrStmt = Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(oPrStmtSelect);
        oRoot = Root.closeDbConnection(null, oRoot);
    }
}
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
      { 
      Snomedinfo a = new Snomedinfo();
      a .snomedinfoinsert();
      }
}
```

Note: how do I do this without using nested while loops? Can someone provide me a solution that is in accordance with my program?

Comment: Use inner queries.

Comment: no the queries has to be seperate,i  dont want to write them as a single query..

Comment: Unrelated: A) read about java naming convents. Class names go UpperCase, and methods go camelCase() B) use names that mean something, and avoid abbreviations. Finally: you expect others to spend their time helping you. So you please properly format/indent your input, instead of dumping such a lazily indented code drop.

Comment: Learn about Java design patterns. Better follow the MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) include the concept-id-selecting query within an `IN` clause:

```
INSERT INTO snomedinfo_data (refid, id, effectivetime, active, moduleid, conceptid, 
                             languagecode, typeid, term, caseSignificanceid) 
    SELECT refid, id, effectivetime, active, moduleid, conceptid, 
                    languagecode, typeid, term, caseSignificanceid 
           FROM snomed_descriptiondata 
           WHERE active = 1 AND conceptid IN 
               (SELECT cd.id FROM snomed_conceptdata cd WHERE cd.active = 1)
```

This way you should be able to do everything in one statement which will be orders of magnitude faster than processing the same data row-by-row (a.k.a slow-by-slow) by the JDBC driver.

Comment: no the queries has to be seperate,i dont want to write them as a single query!!

Comment: so therefore there should be a total of 3 queries in the program.two select queries and 1 insert query

Comment: Can you explain _why_ the queries need to be separate? What are you doing with the intermediate results?

Comment: problem is i dont know how to do this without using nested while loop

Comment: after retrieving 'id' from snomed_conceptdata table  iam selecting only those records from snomed_descriptiondata  where the column conceptid=id

Comment: then iam inserting those records into a 3rd table called 'snomedinfo_data'

Comment: Iam not supposed to be using a single query for both inserting and selecting as it is forbidden in my workplace(office).

Comment: @davidmathew I can't believe it would be 'forbidden' in your workplace, and if it is, maybe they should come up with more sensible policies than enforcing practices that are extremely bad for performance.

Comment: @davidmathew, I think that two distinct `INSERT INTO... SELECT` statements (run within the same transaction) would be the most efficient and simplest way to do this. If you definitely cannot do that (unclear why) then using JDBC batching might help with the performance. No way really to eliminate iterating the result set this way, though.  I'll try to edit the answer to reflect this later today.

Comment: yeah..so according to this program there should be 3 seperate queries.(2 select and 1 insert)

Comment: and without using nested while loop for the sake of performance/efficiency!!